# How do I configure folder access rights?

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

I have to install a Windows XP Professional system on an old computer. The computer is not a member of a doamain.

I have added users to a group and want a folder (tree) to be accessible only for members of this group. Unfortunately I can't find the access right list in the property page of the folder. How do I configure folder access rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the file ACL settings in Windows XP, you must first disable 'Simple File Sharing'

Please see:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307874